# How to make Ant Design table responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I want to make a table similar to gmail inbox table in which the table columns are diaplayed as rows on small screens. I am using Ant Design's table component but I can't find how to make it responsive in the documentation.

What I want on big screens:

| From | To |
| --- | --- |
| aaa@example.com | zzz.zzz@example.com |
| ccc@example.com | yyy.yyy@example.com |

What I want on small screens:

| From To |
| --- |
| aaa@example.com zzz.zzz@example.com |
| ccc@example.com yyy.yyy@example.com |

This is my react code in which I have made a tabl using Ant Design:

```js
import "./App.css";
import { Table } from "antd";

function App() {
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "From",
      dataIndex: "from",
      sorter: (a, b) => a.from.length - b.from.length,
      sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"],
    },
    {
      title: "To",
      dataIndex: "to",
      sorter: (a, b) => a.to - b.to,
      sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"],
    },
    {
      title: "Subject",
      dataIndex: "subject",
      sorter: (a, b) => a.subject.length - b.subject.length,
      sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"],
    },
    {
      title: "Date",
      dataIndex: "date",
      sorter: (a, b) => a.date.length - b.date.length,
      sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"],
    },
  ];

  const data = [
    {
      key: "1",
      from: "aaa@example.com",
      to: "zzz.zzz@example.com",
      subject: "[ HR-888 ] Notice of official announcement",
      date: "0:20",
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      from: "bbb.bbbb@example.com",
      to: "yyy.yyy@example.com",
      subject: `[web:333] "Web Contact"`,
      date: "0:20",
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} pagination={false} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-responsive)?

Comment: Yes, but that example will hide the column

Comment: Please see my [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-antd494-forked-blrwk?file=/index.css)

Comment: Yes this is the correct one please put it in the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can make use of the [`responsive`](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-responsive) property on the column that you want to control for screen sizes. Just add a `From To` column with a custom render function, and set the `responsive` property on that column to only show on `xs` screens. The `From` and `To` columns will have the responsive property set to show on `md` and above.

There is a caveat to this approach. It works if you want `From To` to show on `xs` screens but if you want `From To` to show on `sm` or smaller screens, setting the responsive property to `["sm"]` will break. This is because of how AntDesign implemented their [breakpoint](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/015109b42b85c63146371b4e32b883cf97b088e8/components/_util/responsiveObserve.ts#L1) definitions. Note their `xs` definition is `(max-width: 575px)`. This is the only breakpoint with a `max-width` property. The other breakpoints use `min-width` properties. Therefore setting a responsive property to `["sm"]` means that the column will show on `sm` and larger screens.

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-antd494-forked-blrwk)

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: "From To",
    render: (record) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        {record.from}
        <br />
        {record.to}
      </React.Fragment>
    ),
    responsive: ["xs"]
  },
  {
    title: "From",
    dataIndex: "from",
    sorter: (a, b) => a.from.length - b.from.length,
    sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"],
    responsive: ["sm"]
  },
  {
    title: "To",
    dataIndex: "to",
    sorter: (a, b) => a.to - b.to,
    sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"],
    responsive: ["sm"]
  },
  {
    title: "Subject",
    dataIndex: "subject",
    sorter: (a, b) => a.subject.length - b.subject.length,
    sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"]
  },
  {
    title: "Date",
    dataIndex: "date",
    sorter: (a, b) => a.date.length - b.date.length,
    sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"]
  }
];
```

Comment: only question is why it's not in official documentation)

Comment: I have the same problem with ant design vue regarding the responsive table, it should be the same way but it didn't work https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-ant-design-vue-3-0-0-beta-5-forked-3pqn7

Comment: @Fahmi I'm not a Vue expert but based on the 3.0 API docs, it should work. You can report it as a bug to the devs and have them look at it.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr I already open discussions on the repo https://github.com/vueComponent/ant-design-vue/discussions/5122 but no reply yet. I maybe open the issue but I didn't get any reply from the author yet.

Comment: This no longer works in 2024

Answer (score 2):

Another approach not good but still, you can render a stack or a card containing your data columns.

```
const isWebDevice = useMediaQuery('(min-width:700px)');
const deviceColumns = [
    {
      title: "Student Data",
      render: (record, key, index) => {
         const from = record.from;
         const to = record.to;
         const subject = record.subject;
         const date = record.date;
         return (
             <div>
                  <span>
                        <h4>From</h4>
                        <h4>{from}</h4>
                  </span>
                  <span>
                        <h4>To</h4>
                        <h4>{to}</h4>
                  </span>
                  <span>
                        <h4>Subject</h4>
                        <h4>{subject}</h4>
                  </span>
                  <span>
                        <h4>Date</h4>
                        <h4>{date}</h4>
                  </span>
             </div>
         )
      }
  ];

<Table 
    columns={isWebDevice ? columns : deviceColumns}
    dataSource={data} 
    pagination={false} 
/>
```

like above you can apply classes to `<span>` and render them accordingly using CSS according to devices.